# How to iterate through PostgreSQL jsonb array values for purposes of matching within a query

Tags: json, postgresql

My table has many rows, each containing a jsonb object.

This object holds an array, in which there can potentially be multiple keys of the same name but with different values.

My goal is to scan my entire table and verify which rows contain duplicate values within this json object's array.

Row 1 example data:

```
{
    "Name": "Bobb Smith",
    "Identifiers": [
        {
            "Content": "123",
            "RecordID": "123",
            "SystemID": "Test",
            "LastUpdated": "2017-09-12T02:23:30.817Z"
        },
        {
            "Content": "abc",
            "RecordID": "abc",
            "SystemID": "Test",
            "LastUpdated": "2017-09-13T10:10:21.598Z"
        },
        {
            "Content": "def",
            "RecordID": "def",
            "SystemID": "Test",
            "LastUpdated": "2017-09-13T10:10:21.598Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Row 2 example data:

```
{
    "Name": "Bob Smith",
    "Identifiers": [
        {
            "Content": "abc",
            "RecordID": "abc",
            "SystemID": "Test",
            "LastUpdated": "2017-09-13T10:10:26.020Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

My current query was originally used to find duplicates based on a name value, but, in cases where the names may be flubbed, using a record ID is a more full proof method.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to essentially iterate over each 'Record ID' within every row and compare that 'Record ID' to every other 'Record ID' in every row within the same table to locate matches.

My current query to match 'Name':

```
discard temporary;

with dupe as (
    select 
    json_document->>'Name' as name, 
    json_document->'Identifiers'->0->'RecordID' as record_id, 
    from staging
)


 select name as "Name", record_id::text as "Record ID"
 from dupe da
 where ( select count(*) from dupe db where db.name = da.name) > 1
 order by full_name;
```

The above query would return the matching rows IF the 'Name' field in both rows contained the same spelling of 'Bob'.

I need this same functionality using the nested value of the 'RecordID' field.

The problem here is that 
    `json_document->'Identifiers'->0->'RecordID'`
only returns the 'RecordID' at index 0 within the array.

For example, this does NOT work:

```
discard temporary;
with dupe as (
    select 
    json_document->>'Name' as name, 
    json_document->'Identifiers'->0->'RecordID' as record_id, 
    from staging
)

select name as "Name", record_id::text as "Record ID"
from dupe da
where ( select count(*) from dupe db where db.record_id = da.record_id) > 1
order by full_name;
```

...because the query only checks the 'RecordID' value at index 0 of the 'Identifiers' array.

How could I essentially perform something like
    `SELECT json_document@>'RecordID'`
in order to have my query check every index within the 'Identifiers' array for the 'RecordID' value?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

- I'm hoping to accomplish this with only a Postgres query and NOT by accessing this data with an external language. (Python, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by essentially performing the 'unnest()'-like `jsonb_array_elements()` on my nested jsonb array.

By doing this in a subquery, then scanning those results using a variation of my original query, I was able to achieve my desired result.

Here is what I came up with.

```
with dupe as (
select
json_document->>'Name' as name,
identifiers->'RecordID' as record_id
from (
  select *,  
  jsonb_array_elements(json_document->'Identifiers') as identifiers
  from staging
) sub
group by record_id, json_document
order by name
) 

select * from dupe da where (select count(*) from dupe db where 
db.record_id = da.record_id) > 1;
```