# How can my Postgres query perform faster? Can I use Python to provide faster iteration?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

This is a two-part question.  If you're checking this out, thanks for your time!

1. Is there a way to make my query faster?

   I previously asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225548/how-to-iterate-through-postgresql-jsonb-array-values-for-purposes-of-matching-wi), and was eventually able to solve the problem myself.

   However, the query I devised to produce my desired results is VERY slow (25+ minutes) when run against my database, which contains 40,000+ records.

   The query is serving its purpose, but I'm hoping one of you brilliant people can point out to me how to make the query perform at a more preferred speed.

   My query:

   ```
   with dupe as (
       select
            json_document->'Firstname'->0->'Content' as first_name,
            json_document->'Lastname'->0->'Content' as last_name,
            identifiers->'RecordID' as record_id
       from (
           select *,  
                  jsonb_array_elements(json_document->'Identifiers') as identifiers
           from staging
       ) sub
       group by record_id, json_document
       order by last_name
   ) 

   select * from dupe da where (
     select count(*) from dupe db 
     where db.record_id = da.record_id
   ) > 1;
   ```

   Again, some sample data:

   Row 1:

   ```
   {
           "Firstname": "Bobb",
           "Lastname": "Smith",
           "Identifiers": [
               {
                   "Content": "123",
                   "RecordID": "123",
                   "SystemID": "Test",
                   "LastUpdated": "2017-09-12T02:23:30.817Z"
               },
               {
                   "Content": "abc",
                   "RecordID": "abc",
                   "SystemID": "Test",
                   "LastUpdated": "2017-09-13T10:10:21.598Z"
               },
               {
                   "Content": "def",
                   "RecordID": "def",
                   "SystemID": "Test",
                   "LastUpdated": "2017-09-13T10:10:21.598Z"
               }
           ]
   }
   ```

   Row 2:

   ```
   {
           "Firstname": "Bob",
           "Lastname": "Smith",
           "Identifiers": [
               {
                   "Content": "abc",
                   "RecordID": "abc",
                   "SystemID": "Test",
                   "LastUpdated": "2017-09-13T10:10:26.020Z"
               }
           ]
   }
   ```
2. If I were to bring in my query's results, or a portion of the results, into a Python environment where they could be manipulated using Pandas, how could I iterate over the results of my query (or the sub-query) in order to achieve the same end result as with my original query?

   Is there an easier way, using Python, to iterate through my un-nested json array in the same way that Postgres does?

   For example, after performing this query:

   ```
   select
       json_document->'Firstname'->0->'Content' as first_name,
       json_document->'Lastname'->0->'Content' as last_name,
       identifiers->'RecordID' as record_id
   from (
          select *,  
                 jsonb_array_elements(json_document->'Identifiers') as identifiers
          from staging
        ) sub
   order by last_name;
   ```

   How, using Python/Pandas, can i take that query's results and perform something like:

   ```
   da = datasets[query_results]  # to equal my dupe da query
   db = datasets[query_results]  # to equal my dupe db query
   ```

   Then perform the equivalent of

   ```
   select * from dupe da where (
       select count(*) from dupe db 
       where db.record_id = da.record_id
   ) > 1;
   ```

   in Python?

I apologize if I do not provide enough information here. I am a Python novice. Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: First convert from using a CTE (`WITH` query) to using subquery-in-FROM form. See https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/

Comment: Thanks Craig! I'm reading this now, and it looks like this could help some. +1

Comment: It's *almost always* faster to do things in SQL than client-side iteration, once you figure out how. Sometimes it takes some extra thought. Please show `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output for your query too, btw, in an edit.

Comment: Have any of the suggestions resulted in a faster query?

Comment: @CraigRinger Sorry i didn't get around to adding the 'Explain Analyze' output.  BUT, your suggestion was vastly helpful.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, which eliminates your count(*) and instead uses exists.

```
 with dupe as ( 
   select id, 
     json_document->'Firstname'->0->'Content' as first_name, 
     json_document->'Lastname'->0->'Content' as last_name, 
     identifiers->'RecordID' as record_id 
   from 
     (select 
       *, 
       jsonb_array_elements(json_document->'Identifiers') as identifiers 
      from staging ) sub 
      group by
        id,
        record_id, 
        json_document 
      order by last_name ) 
 select * from dupe da 
   where exists 
     (select * 
       from dupe db 
       where 
         db.record_id = da.record_id 
         and db.id != da.id
     )
```

Comment: thanks!  This does in fact speed my query up immensely.  I made a slight edit to the query you posted above, but the general idea was spot on.  Thanks again!

Comment: Did I have a typo? Let me know what you changed and I'll update the answer for posterity.

Comment: As above, `dupe da` does not include the primary key `id`.  I just needed to add `id` to the list of items in my SELECT statement within my `WITH dupe AS` query, so it could be accessed by my final SELECT *.  ;)

The nested sub-query already performs SELECT *, so `id` doesn't need to be included in the SELECT statement there.  Just added to the GROUP BY list.

Comment: ```with dupe as (
select
id,
json_document->'Firstname'->0->'Content' as first_name,
json_document->'Lastname'->0->'Content' as last_name,
identifiers->'RecordID' as record_id
from (
  select *,  
  jsonb_array_elements(json_document->'Identifiers') as identifiers
  from staging
) sub
group by id, record_id, json_document
order by last_name
) 

select * from dupe da where exists (
  select * from dupe db 
  where db.record_id = da.record_id
  and db.id != da.id
) ``` works :)

Comment: If I may ask, how much faster did this wind up being?

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading the raw, unqueried values of the Postgres json column type and use pandas [`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) to bind into a flat dataframe. From there use pandas [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

To demonstrate, below parses your one json data into three-row dataframe for each corresponding *Identifiers* records:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

json_str = '''
{
        "Firstname": "Bobb",
        "Lastname": "Smith",
        "Identifiers": [
            {
                "Content": "123",
                "RecordID": "123",
                "SystemID": "Test",
                "LastUpdated": "2017-09-12T02:23:30.817Z"
            },
            {
                "Content": "abc",
                "RecordID": "abc",
                "SystemID": "Test",
                "LastUpdated": "2017-09-13T10:10:21.598Z"
            },
            {
                "Content": "def",
                "RecordID": "def",
                "SystemID": "Test",
                "LastUpdated": "2017-09-13T10:10:21.598Z"
            }
        ]
}
'''

data = json.loads(json_str)    
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, 'Identifiers', ['Firstname','Lastname'])

print(df)    
#   Content               LastUpdated RecordID SystemID Lastname Firstname
# 0     123  2017-09-12T02:23:30.817Z      123     Test    Smith      Bobb
# 1     abc  2017-09-13T10:10:21.598Z      abc     Test    Smith      Bobb
# 2     def  2017-09-13T10:10:21.598Z      def     Test    Smith      Bobb
```

---

For your database, consider connecting with your DB-API such as `psycopg2` or [sqlAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html) and parse each json as a string accordingly. Admittedly, there may be other ways to handle json as seen in the [psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#additional-data-types) but below receives data as text and parses on python side:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")

cur = conn.cursor()    
cur.execute("SELECT json_document::text FROM staging;")

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize([json.loads(row[0]) for row in cur.fetchall()], 
                               'Identifiers', ['Firstname','Lastname'])

df = df.drop_duplicates(['RecordID'])

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.